# MVC 3 Details View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC frame work. And i am making one page where we can see details of department by clicking on details link button.

While User click link button it fetch the all the records of the particular department in List Collection and redirect to Details View.Data has been fetched in List but while going to Details view it Generates following error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '`System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DocPageSys.Models.Interfaces.DepartmentInfo]`', but this dictionary requires a model item of type '`DocPageSys.Models.Interfaces.DepartmentInfo`'.

I understood the error but confusion to solve it.And stuck with this problem...

Comment: Can you show us the first lines of your view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `Details` view is strongly typed to `DepartmentInfo`:

```
@model DocPageSys.Models.Interfaces.DepartmentInfo
```

you need to pass a single instance of it from the controller action instead of a list:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    DepartmentInfo depInfo = db.Departments.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    return View(depInfo);
}
```

So make sure that when you are calling the `return View()` method from your controller action you are passing a single `DepartmentInfo` instance that you have fetched from your data store.

To make it run fine initially you could simply hardcode some value in it:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var depInfo = new DepartmentInfo
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Sales",
        Manager = "John Smith"
    }
    return View(depInfo);
}
```

Oh, and you will notice that I didn't use any ViewData/ViewBag. You don't need it. Due to their weakly typed nature it makes things look really ugly. I would recommend you to always use view models.

Answer (score 0):

### Passing a list instead of a single item

This error tells you, that you're passing a list to your view but should be passing a single entity object instance.

If you did fetch a single item but is in a list you can easily just do:

```
return View(result[0]);
```

or a more robust code:

```
if (result != null && result.Count == 1)
{
    return View(result[0]);
}
return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
```

Answer (score 0):

This error will typically occur when there is a mismatch between the data that the controller action passes to the view and the type of data the view is expecting.

In this instance it looks as if you're passing a list of DepartmentInfo items when your view is expecting a single item.